# Calling collect() on Spark custom RDD resulting in an empty collection

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For the following RDD (relevant sections shown):

```
val myRdd = new RDD[RddOutput](zippedRows) {

  override def compute(split: Partition, context: TaskContext): Iterator[RddOutput] = {
       ..
      val out =  // computes a list of items
    }
    out.toIterator  // Breakpoint set here: out is non-empty
  }

}
```

When invoking the rdd:

```
val outVects = myRdd.collect
val veclen = outVects(0).size    // outVects is null!
```

So as the comments note: the output iterator withint the compute() is non-empty but then there is no data returned from the collect() invocation.   Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to create a new RDD? Is zippedRows.map/mapPartitions nt enough?

Comment: @zsxwing  There is an issue with Broadcast that is driving that choice. If / when that issue were resolved a custom RDD will not be necessary.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without an example that we could run. This works for me: `new RDD[Int](sc.parallelize(1 to 10)) { override def compute(split: Partition, context: TaskContext) = Seq(1, 2).iterator; override def getPartitions = firstParent[Int].partitions }.collect`.

Comment: In your example you take `outVects(0).size`. What is empty? `outVects` or `outVects(0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to have been related to inconsistent partitioning scheme. The MyRdd was given the same partitions as the parent. Then I added a transformation step but did not update the partitioning to point to the new parent: the partitioning was pointing to the new grandparent RDD.